# Who is calling the Java Thread interrupt() method if I'm not?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I've read and re-read Java Concurrency in Practice, I've read several threads here on the subject, I've read the IBM article [Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236.html) and yet there's something I'm simply not grasping which I think can be broken down into two questions:

1. If I'm never ever interrupting other threads myself, what can trigger an *InterruptedException*?
2. If I'm never ever interrupting other threads myself using *interrupt()* (say because I'm using other means to cancel my working threads, like poison pills and *while (!cancelled)* style loop [as both explained in JCIP]), what does an *InterruptedException* then mean?  What am I supposed to do upon catching one?  Shutdown my app?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The Thread interrupt mechanism is the preferred way to get a (cooperating) thread to respond a request to stop what it is doing.  Any thread (including the thread itself I think) could call `interrupt()` on a Thread.

In practice, the normal use-cases for `interrupt()` involve some kind of framework or manager telling some worker thread to stop what they are doing.  If the worker thread is "interrupt aware" it will notice that it has been interrupted via an exception, or by periodically checking its interrupted flag.  On noticing that it has been interrupted, a well-behaved thread would abandon what it is doing and end itself.

Assuming the above use-case, your code is likely to be interrupted if it is run within a Java framework or from some worker thread.  And when it is interrupted, your code should abandon what it is doing and cause itself to end by the most appropriate means.  Depending on how your code was called, this might be done by returning or by throwing some appropriate exception.  But it probably should not call `System.exit()`.  (Your application does not necessarily know why it was interrupted, and it certainly does not know if there are other threads that need to be interrupted by the framework.)

On the other hand, if your code is not designed to run under the control of some framework, you could argue that the `InterruptedException` is an unexpected exception; i.e. a bug.  In that case, you should treat the exception as you would other bugs; e.g. wrap it in an unchecked exception, and catch and log it at the same point you deal with other unexpected unchecked exceptions.  (Alternatively, your application could simply ignore the interrupt and continue doing what it was doing.)

---

> 1) If I'm never ever interrupting other threads myself, what can trigger an InterruptedException?

One example is if your `Runnable` objects are executed using an `ExecutorService` and `shutdownNow()` is called on the service.  And in theory, any 3rd-party thread pool or thread management framework could legitimately do something like this.

> 2) If I'm never ever interrupting other threads myself using interrupt() ... what does an `InterruptedException` then mean? What am I supposed to do upon catching one? Shutdown my app?

You need analyze the codebase to figure out what is making the `interrupt()` calls and why.  Once you have figured that out, you can work out what >>your<< part of the app needs to do.

Until you know why `InterruptedException` is being thrown, I would advise treating it as a hard error; e.g. print a stacktrace to the log file and shut down the app.  (Obviously, that's not always the right answer ... but the point is that this is "a bug", and it needs to be brought to the attention of the developer / maintainer.)

> 3) How do I find out who / what is calling `interrupt()`?

There is no good answer to this.  The best I can suggest is to set a breakpoint on the `Thread.interrupt()` and look at the call stack.

Answer (score 12):

If you decide to integrate your code with other libraries, they can call `interrupt()` on your code. e.g. if you decide in the future to execute your code within an [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), then that may force a shutdown via `interrupt()`.

To put it briefly, I would consider not just where your code is running *now*, but in what context it may run in the future. e.g. are you going to put it in a library ? A container ? How will other people use it ? Are you going to reuse it ?

Comment: I thought only shutdownNow calls the interrupt() method. Is it true for shutdown as well?

Answer (score 9):

As others have pointed out, interrupting a thread (actually, interrupting a blocking call) is usually used for purposes of exiting cleanly or cancelling an ongoing activity.

However, you should not treat an `InterruptedException` alone as a "quit command". Instead, you should think of interrupts as a means to control the running status of threads, much in the same way as `Object.notify()` does. In the same way that you'd check the current state after waking up from a call to `Object.wait()` (you don't assume that the wakeup means your wait condition has been satisfied), after being nudged with an interrupt you should check *why* you were interrupted. There is usually a way to do this. For example, `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` has an `isCancelled()` method.

Code sample:

```
public void run() {
    ....
    try {
        .... // Calls that may block.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        if (!running) {  // Add preferred synchronization here.
            return; // Explicit flag says we should stop running.
        }
        // We were interrupted, but the flag says we're still running.
        // It would be wrong to always exit here. The interrupt 'nudge'
        // could mean something completely different. For example, it
        // could be that the thread was blocking on a read from a particular
        // file, and now we should read from a different file.
        // Interrupt != quit (not necessarily).
    }
    ....
}
public void stop() {
    running = false; // Add preferred synchronization here.
    myThread.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the question is "I". "I" usually refers to a single instance of a class. I mean by that, that any particular piece of low-level code (class) should not rely upon the implementation of the entire system. Having said that you do have make some "architectural" decisions (like what platform to run on).

Possible unexpected interrupts coming from the JRE are canceled tasks in `java.util.concurrent` and shutting down applets.

Handling of thread interrupts is usually written incorrectly. Therefore, I suggest the architectural decision to avoid causing interrupts where possible. However, code handling interrupts should always be written correctly. Can't take interrupts out of the platform now.

Comment: Hi Tom, I remember your name from c.l.j.p. ;)   Well, precisely: I never had to throw *interrupt()* myself... Unless I'm catching an InterruptedException and need to re-assert the interrupted status but this is still not 100% clear to me.  I'm new here and surprised by the number of upvotes and answers/comments (both the correct ones and the wrong ones): obviously it's a subject that is not trivial or, at least, usually not well explained.  That said thanks to all the posts I'm beginning to get a clearer picture of what's going on :)

Answer (score 3):

You could learn this by creating your own thread class (extending `java.lang.Thread`) and overriding `interrupt()` method, in which you record the stacktrace into, say, a String field, and then transfer to super.interrupt().

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public volatile String interruptStacktrace; // Temporary field for debugging purpose.

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        interruptStacktrace = dumpStack(); // You implement it somehow...

        super.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, another library can interrupt your threads. Even if the library doesn't have explicit access to the threads from your code, they can still get the list of threads that are running and interrupt them that way with the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java/1323480#1323480).

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand why you are a bit confused about interruption. Please consider my answers in line:

> If I'm never ever interrupting other threads myself, what can trigger an *InterruptedException*?

Firstly you may interrupt other threads; I know that in JCiP it is mentioned that you should never interrupt threads you do not own; however, this statement has to be properly understood. What it means is that your code which might be running in any arbitrary thread should not handle interruption because since it is not the owner of the thread it has no clue of its interruption policy. So you may request interruption on other threads, but let its owner take the course of interruption action; it has the interruption policy encapsulated within it, not your task code; at least be courteous to set the interruption flag!

There are many ways why there could be interruptions still, may be timeouts, JVM interrupts etc.

> If I'm never ever interrupting other threads myself using interrupt() (say because I'm using other means to cancel my working threads, like poison pills and while (!cancelled) style loop [as both explained in JCIP]), what does an InterruptedException then mean? What am I supposed to do upon catching one? Shutdown my app?

You need to be very careful here; if you own the thread which threw InterruptedException (IE), then you know what to do upon catching it, say you may shutdown your app/service or you may replace this killed thread with a new one! However, if you do not own the thread then upon catching IE either rethrow it higher up the call stack or after doing something (may be logging), reset the interrupted status so that the code which owns this thread, when control reaches it, may learn that the thread was interrupted and hence take actions as it will since only it knows the interruption policy.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The `InterruptedException` says that a routine *may* be interrupted, but not necessarily that it will be.

If you don't expect the interrupt then you should treat it as you might any other unexpected exception. If it's in a critical section where an unexpected exception could have heinous consequences, it might be best to try and clean up resources and gracefully shutdown (because getting the interrupt signals that your well-engineered application that doesn't rely on interrupts is being used in a way it wasn't designed, and so there must be something wrong). Alternatively, if the code in question is something non-critical or trivial, you might want to ignore (or log) the interrupt and keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has mentioned it: interrupts can occur as a reaction to signals sent by the operating system. For example, `kill -SIGINT <pid>` can send an interrupt signal to your process, which your process can then translate into a Thread interrupt. By default, however, the JVM already handles SIGINT (and others such as SIGTERM) in a particular way. So, if you want to handle SIGINT in a specific way, you'd need to configure the JVM and your app accordingly.

Often, web frameworks will add shutdown hooks which allow you to gracefully end work. Often, your code should attempt to shut down things like `ExecutorService` instances gracefully, with some timeout, after which you should interrupt your threads. Your threads, in turn, should respond in a timely manner to that interrupt, so that your app does not take too long to shut down. However, this only matters if your app needs to try to finish up its current work.