# How to cancel Java 8 completable future?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

I am playing with Java 8 completable futures. I have the following code:

```
CountDownLatch waitLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("Wait");
        waitLatch.await(); //cancel should interrupt
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});

sleep(10); //give it some time to start (ugly, but works)
future.cancel(true);
System.out.println("Cancel called");

assertTrue(future.isCancelled());

assertTrue(future.isDone());
sleep(100); //give it some time to finish
```

Using runAsync I schedule execution of a code that waits on a latch. Next I cancel the future, expecting an interrupted exception to be thrown inside. But it seems that the thread remains blocked on the await call and the InterruptedException is never thrown even though the future is canceled (assertions pass). An equivalent code using ExecutorService works as expected. Is it a bug in the CompletableFuture or in my example?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` vs `Executors.newWorkStealingPool`? It would make the question clearer to compare two different executor implementations than comparing futures vs. completable futures.

Comment: The JavaDoc says that cancel(true) cancels with a CancellationException but you're not catching that.

Comment: @nosid You are right, newWorkStealingPool apparently does not support cancel neither

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently, it's intentional. The Javadoc for the method [CompletableFuture::cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) states:

> *[Parameters:]* mayInterruptIfRunning - this value has **no** effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

Interestingly, the method [ForkJoinTask::cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#cancel-boolean-) uses almost the same wording for the parameter *mayInterruptIfRunning*.

I have a guess on this issue:

- *interruption* is intended to be used with blocking operations, like *sleep*, *wait* or I/O operations,
- but neither *CompletableFuture* nor *ForkJoinTask* are intended to be used with blocking operations.

Instead of blocking, a *CompletableFuture* should create a new *CompletionStage*, and cpu-bound tasks are a prerequisite for the fork-join model. So, using *interruption* with either of them would defeat their purpose. And on the other hand, it might increase complexity, that's not required if used as intended.

Comment: Why do you think that _CompletableFuture_ and _ForkJoinTask_ are not intended to be used with blocking operations?

Comment: The whole point of CompletableFuture and other reactive stuff is: don't waste threads by making them wait for the result of some long operation. Instead, provide a callback to be called when the result is here. Reactive approach requires way less threads.

Comment: My previous comment is not precisely correct. CompletableFuture allows for uniform syntax for both blocking and non-blocking code. That may be useful during migration of codebase from blocking style to non-blocking

Answer (score 40):

When you call `CompletableFuture#cancel`, you only stop the downstream part of the chain. Upstream part, i. e. something that will eventually call `complete(...)` or `completeExceptionally(...)`, doesn't get any signal that the result is no more needed.

What are those 'upstream' and 'downstream' things?

Let's consider the following code:

```
CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> "hello")               //1
        .thenApply(s -> s + " world!")            //2
        .thenAccept(s -> System.out.println(s));  //3
```

Here, the data flows from top to bottom - from being created by supplier, through being modified by function, to being consumed by `println`. The part above particular step is called upstream, and the part below is downstream. E. g. steps 1 and 2 are upstream for step 3.

Here's what happens behind the scenes. This is not precise, rather it's a convenient mind model of what's going on.

1. Supplier (step 1) is being executed (inside the JVM's common `ForkJoinPool`).
2. The result of the supplier is then being passed by `complete(...)` to the next `CompletableFuture` downstream.
3. Upon receiving the result, that `CompletableFuture` invokes next step - a function (step 2) which takes in previous step result and returns something that will be passed further, to the downstream `CompletableFuture`'s `complete(...)`.
4. Upon receiving the step 2 result, step 3 `CompletableFuture` invokes the consumer, `System.out.println(s)`. After consumer is finished, the downstream `CompletableFuture` will receive it's value, `(Void) null`

As we can see, each `CompletableFuture` in this chain has to know who are there downstream waiting for the value to be passed to their's `complete(...)` (or `completeExceptionally(...)`). But the `CompletableFuture` don't have to know anything about it's upstream (or upstreams - there might be several).

Thus, **calling `cancel()` upon step 3 doesn't abort steps 1 and 2**, because there's no link from step 3 to step 2.

It is supposed that if you're using `CompletableFuture` then your steps are small enough so that there's no harm if a couple of extra steps will get executed.

If you want cancellation to be propagated upstream, you have two options:

- Implement this yourself - create a dedicated `CompletableFuture` (name it like `cancelled`) which is checked after every step (something like `step.applyToEither(cancelled, Function.identity())`)
- Use reactive stack like RxJava 2, ProjectReactor/Flux or Akka Streams

Answer (score 9):

If you actually want to be able to cancel a task, then you have to use `Future` itself (e.g. as returned by `ExecutorService.submit(Callable<T>)`, not `CompletableFuture`. As pointed out in the answer by **nosid**, `CompletableFuture` completely ignores any call to `cancel(true)`.

My suspicion is that the JDK team did not implement interruption because:

1. Interruption was always hacky, difficult for people to understand, and difficult to work with. The Java I/O system is not even interruptible, despite calls to `InputStream.read()` being blocking calls! (And the JDK team have no plans to make the standard I/O system interruptible again, like it was in the very early Java days.)
2. The JDK team have been trying very hard to phase out old broken APIs from the early Java days, such as `Object.finalize()`, `Object.wait()`, `Thread.stop()`, etc.  I believe `Thread.interrupt()` is considered to be in the category of things that must be eventually deprecated and replaced. Therefore, newer APIs (like `ForkJoinPool` and `CompletableFuture`) are already not supporting it.
3. `CompletableFuture` was designed for building DAG-structured pipelines of operations, similar to the Java `Stream` API. It's very dificult to succinctly describe how interruption of one node of a dataflow DAG should affect execution in the rest of the DAG. (Should all concurrent tasks be canceled immediately, when any node is interrupted?)
4. I suspect the JDK team just didn't want to deal with getting interruption right, given the levels of internal complexity that the JDK and libraries have reached these days. (The internals of the lambda system -- ugh.)

One very hacky way around this would be to have each `CompletableFuture` export a reference to itself to an externally-visible `AtomicReference`, then the `Thread` reference could be interrupted directly when needed from another external thread. Or if you start all the tasks using your own `ExecutorService`, in your own `ThreadPool`, you can manually interrupt any or all the threads that were started, even if `CompletableFuture` refuses to trigger interruption via `cancel(true)`. (Note though that `CompletableFuture` lambdas cannot throw checked exceptions, so if you have an interruptible wait in a `CompletableFuture`, you'll have to re-throw as an unchecked exception.)

More simply, you could just declare an `AtomicReference<Boolean> cancel = new AtomicReference<>()` in an external scope, and periodically check this flag from inside each `CompletableFuture` task's lambda.

You could also try setting up a DAG of `Future` instances rather than a DAG of `CompletableFuture` instances, that way you can exactly specify how exceptions and interruption/cancellation in any one task should affect the other currently-running tasks. [I show how to do this in my example code in my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65073632/3950982), and it works well, but it's a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

You need an alternative implementation of CompletionStage to accomplish true thread interruption. I've just released a small library that serves exactly this purpose - https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent

Answer (score 2):

The call to wait will still block even if `Future.cancel(..)` is called. As mentioned by others the `CompletableFuture` will not use interrupts to cancel the task.

According to the javadoc of `CompletableFuture.cancel(..)`:

> *mayInterruptIfRunning* this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

Even if the implementation would cause an interrupt, you would still need a blocking operation in order to cancel the task or check the status via `Thread.interrupted()`.

Instead of interrupting the `Thread`, which might not be always easy to do, you may have check points in your operation where you can gracefully terminate the current task. This can be done in a loop over some elements that will be processed or you check before each step of the operation for the cancel status and throw an `CancellationException` yourself.

The tricky part is to get a reference of the `CompletableFuture` within the task in order to call `Future.isCancelled()`. Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
public abstract class CancelableTask<T> {

    private CompletableFuture<T> task;

    private T run() {
        try {
            return compute();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            task.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected abstract T compute() throws Exception;

    protected boolean isCancelled() {
        Future<T> future = task;
        return future != null && future.isCancelled();
    }

    public Future<T> start() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (task != null) throw new IllegalStateException("Task already started.");
            task = new CompletableFuture<>();
        }
        return task.completeAsync(this::run);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here the improved `CancelableTask` version as a static factory:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Function<Future<T>, T> operation) {
    CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    return future.completeAsync(() -> operation.apply(future));
}
```

here is the test method:

```
@Test
void testFuture() throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch started = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);

    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    Future<Object> future = supplyAsync(task -> {
        started.countDown();
        while (!task.isCancelled()) {
            System.out.println("Count: " + counter.getAndIncrement());
        }
        System.out.println("Task cancelled");
        done.countDown();
        return null;
    });

    // wait until the task is started
    assertTrue(started.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    future.cancel(true);
    System.out.println("Cancel called");

    assertTrue(future.isCancelled());

    assertTrue(future.isDone());
    assertTrue(done.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

If you really want to use interrupts in addition to the `CompletableFuture`, then you can pass a custom `Executor` to `CompletableFuture.completeAsync(..)` where you create your own `Thread`, override `cancel(..)` in the `CompletableFuture` and interrupt your `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

The CancellationException is part of the internal ForkJoin cancel routine. The exception will come out when you retrieve the result of future:

```
try { future.get(); }
      catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.toString());            
      }
```

Took a while to see this in a debugger. The JavaDoc is not that clear on what is happening or what you should expect.