# Why does CompletableFuture implement the Future interface

Tags: java, concurrency, future, completable-future, liskov-substitution-principle

in Java 8, the param `mayInterruptIfRunning` of method `CompletableFuture#cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)` not take effect, which I think violate contract defined in `java.util.concurrent.Future`.

It will cause problem when migrate code from `Future` to `CompletableFuture` without noticing this contract change.

Also it seems violate Liskov substitution principle.

related article: https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/03/completablefuture-cant-be-interrupted.html

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: How do you test that? `may` is not `must`.

Comment: once a thread is started it cannot be interuppted. Upstream nothing can be done

Comment: @BOTJr. eeerrrr [`Thread.interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())??

Comment: mayInterruptIfRunning is the param name, not doc, please read the doc in Future. @Antoniossss

Comment: But the task must handle interruption it first place. I checked the docs prior to my comment, and that was the conclusion.

Comment: @BOTJr. would you please give more detail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23329340/5871514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel Java 8 completable future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320407/how-to-cancel-java-8-completable-future)

Comment: @BOTJr. the link does not answer the question, interruption can use in non-blocking , and interruption status is widely used by this way:`while(!Thread.interrupted){do non-blocking things}`

Comment: The documentation of `CompletableFuture#cancel(boolean)` tells you the why: "_this value has no effect in this implementation **because interrupts are not used to control processing**_". This change in behavior may violate the contract of `Future` and/or some principles, but that's the reason they give. Implementation wise, the `CompletableFuture` does not maintain a reference to the executing thread and thus can't interrupt it.

Comment: @Slaw @BOTJr I see the doc in `CompletableFuture`, it means `cancel` can only effect on downstream. But it can not take effect on stage which is currently running, which I think is a problem.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous (edited) comment, the `CompletableFuture` does not hold a reference to either the actual work or the `Thread` processing it. This is at least implied in the class documentation: "_Since (unlike FutureTask) this class has no direct control over the computation that causes it to be completed, cancellation is treated as just another form of exceptional completion_".

Comment: @Slaw yeah, `CompletableFuture` does not hold reference to thread, which I think it is also a problem, It is not consistency with `Future`.

Comment: @Slaw Agree, I changed the title.