# Constructing a DAG of cancelable Java tasks

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, futuretask

I want to create a DAG out of tasks in Java, where the tasks may depend upon the output of other tasks. If there is no directed path between two tasks, they may run in parallel. Tasks may be canceled. If any task throws an exception, all tasks are canceled.

I wanted to use `CompleteableFuture` for this, but despite implementing the `Future` interface (including `Future.cancel(boolean)`, [`CompletableFuture` does not support cancelation](http://blog.tremblay.pro/2017/08/supply-async.html) -- `CompletableFuture.cancel(true)` is simply ignored. (Does anybody know why?)

Therefore, I am resorting to building my own DAG of tasks using `Future`. It's a lot of boilerplate, and complicated to get right. Is there any better method than this?

Here is an example:

1. I want to call `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` to start a commandline process, creating a `Future<Process>`. Then I want to launch (fan out to) three subtasks:

   - One task that consumes input from `process.getInputStream()`
   - One task that consumes input from `process.getErrorStream()`
   - One task that calls `process.waitFor()`, and then waits for the result.
2. Then I want to wait for all three of the launched sub-tasks to complete (i.e. fan-in / a completion barrier). This should be collected in a final `Future<Integer> exitCode` that collects the exit code returned by the `process.waitFor()` task. The two input consumer tasks simply return `Void`, so their output can be ignored, but the completion barrier should still wait for their completion.

I want a failure in any of the launched subtasks to cause all subtasks to be canceled, and the underlying process destroyed.

Note that `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` in the first step can throw an exception, which should cause the failure to cascade all the way to `exitCode`.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public static interface ConsumerThrowingIOException<T> {
    public void accept(T val) throws IOException;
}

public static Future<Integer> exec(
        ConsumerThrowingIOException<InputStream> stdoutConsumer,
        ConsumerThrowingIOException<InputStream> stderrConsumer,
        String... cmd) {

    Future<Process> processFuture = executor.submit(
            () -> Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd));

    AtomicReference<Future<Void>> stdoutProcessorFuture = //
            new AtomicReference<>();
    AtomicReference<Future<Void>> stderrProcessorFuture = //
            new AtomicReference<>();
    AtomicReference<Future<Integer>> exitCodeFuture = //
            new AtomicReference<>();

    Runnable cancel = () -> {
        try {
            processFuture.get().destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore (exitCodeFuture.get() will still detect exceptions)
        }
        if (stdoutProcessorFuture.get() != null) {
            stdoutProcessorFuture.get().cancel(true);
        }
        if (stderrProcessorFuture.get() != null) {
            stderrProcessorFuture.get().cancel(true);
        }
        if (exitCodeFuture.get() != null) {
            stderrProcessorFuture.get().cancel(true);
        }
    };

    if (stdoutConsumer != null) {
        stdoutProcessorFuture.set(executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = processFuture.get()
                        .getInputStream();
                stdoutConsumer.accept(inputStream != null
                        ? inputStream
                        : new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                cancel.run();
                throw e;
            }
        }));
    }

    if (stderrConsumer != null) {
        stderrProcessorFuture.set(executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                InputStream errorStream = processFuture.get()
                        .getErrorStream();
                stderrConsumer.accept(errorStream != null
                        ? errorStream
                        : new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                cancel.run();
                throw e;
            }
        }));
    }

    exitCodeFuture.set(executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            return processFuture.get().waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            cancel.run();
            throw e;
        }
    }));

    // Async completion barrier -- wait for process to exit,
    // and for output processors to complete
    return executor.submit(() -> {
        Exception exception = null;
        int exitCode = 1;
        try {
            exitCode = exitCodeFuture.get().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | CancellationException
                | ExecutionException e) {
            cancel.run();
            exception = e;
        }
        if (stderrProcessorFuture.get() != null) {
            try {
                stderrProcessorFuture.get().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | CancellationException
                    | ExecutionException e) {
                cancel.run();
                if (exception == null) {
                    exception = e;
                } else if (e instanceof ExecutionException) {
                    exception.addSuppressed(e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (stdoutProcessorFuture.get() != null) {
            try {
                stdoutProcessorFuture.get().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | CancellationException
                    | ExecutionException e) {
                cancel.run();
                if (exception == null) {
                    exception = e;
                } else if (e instanceof ExecutionException) {
                    exception.addSuppressed(e);
                }
            }
        }
        if (exception != null) {
            throw exception;
        } else {
            return exitCode;
        }
    });
}
```

Note: I realize that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` should be non-blocking, so doesn't require its own `Future`, but I wrote the code using one anyway, to make the point about DAG construction.

Comment: CompletableFuture does not support cancelation, unless you shutdown the underlying pool and your threads react to interruptions. And fan-out is just a `flatMap`?

Comment: @Eugene then what does `CompletableFuture.cancel(true)` do? Yes, of course, the threads need to react to interruption to make this work, but for the example I gave, all three sub-tasks are blocking, therefore would need to catch `InterruptedException` internally anyway, and rethrow it as a `CompletionException`. And I don't think fan-out is just a `flatMap`, because for fan-out to work, the three sub-tasks need to be able to be launched from within the parent task -- or on the completion of the parent task -- which adds complexity.

Comment: cancel will not interrupt, read the documentation. It literally says that

Comment: @Eugene I updated the question to use `Future` rather than `CompletableFuture` -- thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score -1):

No way. Process has no asynchronous interface (except for Process.onExit()). So you have to use threads to wait for process creation and while reading from InputStreams. Other components of your DAG can be async tasks (CompletableFutures).

This is not a big problem. The only advantage of async tasks over threads is less memory consumption. Your Process consumes a lot if memery anyway, so there is not much sense to save memory here.

Comment: I think you missed the whole point of my question. `Process` launches another thread that runs in parallel, although `waitFor()` will block on that thread's exit. The whole reason I'm trying to use `CompletableFuture` is to make the exit code from `waitFor()`, and stdout/stderr from the process, available asynchronously.

Comment: stdout/stderr have only blocking interface, they are not available asynchronously. Of course, you always can convert synchronous interface to asynchronoud (but not vice versa), but it would be pure waste of resources.

Comment: waitFor already returns exit code, no intermediate CompletableFuture required.