# How to cancel a task if new instance of task is started?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

My application contains a `ListView` that kicks off a background task every time an item is selected. The background task then updates information on the UI when it completes successfully.

However, when the user quickly clicks one item after another, all these tasks continue and the last task to complete "wins" and updates the UI, regardless of which item was selected last.

What I need is to somehow ensure this task only has one instance of it running at any given time, so cancel all prior tasks before starting the new one.

Here is an MCVE that demonstrates the issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class taskRace  extends Application {

    private final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    private final Label label = new Label("Nothing selected");
    private String labelValue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Simple UI
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, label);

        // Populate the ListView
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
        );

        // Add listener to the ListView to start the task whenever an item is selected
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (newValue != null) {

                // Create the background task
                Task task = new Task() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {

                        String selectedItem = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                        // Do long-running task (takes random time)
                        long waitTime = (long)(Math.random() * 15000);
                        System.out.println("Waiting " + waitTime);
                        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                        labelValue = "You have selected item: " + selectedItem ;
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                // Update the label when the task is completed
                task.setOnSucceeded(event ->{
                    label.setText(labelValue);
                });

                new Thread(task).start();
            }

        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

When clicking on several items in random order, the outcome is unpredictable. What I need is for the label to be updated to show the results from the last `Task` that was executed.

Do I need to somehow schedule the tasks or add them to a service in order to cancel all prior tasks?

**EDIT:**

In my real world application, the user selects an item from the `ListView` and the background task reads a database ( a complex `SELECT` statement) to get all the information associated with that item. Those details are then displayed in the application.

The issue that is happening is when the user selects an item but changes their selection, the data returned displayed in the application could be for the first item selected, even though a completely different item is now chosen.

Any data returned from the first (ie: unwanted) selection can be discarded entirely.

Comment: Could I know what really the task does? I mean what business rule for the task? And then when you said cancel, what does it really mean? Suppose if a task is performing a REST call or perform a Stored Procedure ... we need to know what really cancelled task is.

Comment: @NghiaDo - See my edit. Thank you.

Comment: So, should end-user wait until the task finish before allow user select a new item?

Comment: No, I would like them to be able to move on and select a new item whenever they wish.

Comment: What is the max time of a task may take?

Comment: It is dependent on too many factors and can vary greatly depending on the item selected.

Comment: I have created a tiny example to see if it fits for your case or not. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirements, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51352210/6395627) mentions, seem like a perfect reason for using a [`Service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html). A `Service` allows you to run *one* `Task` at any given time in a reusable<sup>1</sup> manner. When you cancel a `Service`, via `Service.cancel()`, it cancels the underlying `Task`. The `Service` also keeps track of its own `Task` *for you* so you don't need to keep them in a list somewhere.

Using your MVCE what you'd want to do is create a `Service` that wraps your `Task`. Every time the user selects a new item in the `ListView` you'd cancel the `Service`, update the necessary state, and then restart the `Service`. Then you'd use the `Service.setOnSucceeded` callback to set the result to the `Label`. This guarantees that only the last successful execution will be returned to you. Even if previously cancelled `Task`s still return a result the `Service` will ignore them.

You also don't need to worry about external synchronization (at least in your MVCE). All the operations that deal with starting, cancelling, and observing the `Service` happen on the FX thread. The only bit of code (featured below) *not* executed on the FX thread will be inside `Task.call()` (well, and the immediately assigned fields when the class gets instantiated which I believe happens on the JavaFX-Launcher thread).

Here is a modified version of your MVCE using a `Service`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    private final Label label = new Label("Nothing selected");

    private final QueryService service = new QueryService();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        service.setOnSucceeded(wse -> {
            label.setText(service.getValue());
            service.reset();
        });
        service.setOnFailed(wse -> {
            // you could also show an Alert to the user here
            service.getException().printStackTrace();
            service.reset();
        });

        // Simple UI
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, label);

        // Populate the ListView
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
        );

        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (service.isRunning()) {
                service.cancel();
                service.reset();
            }
            service.setSelected(newValue);
            service.start();
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

    }

    private static class QueryService extends Service<String> {

        // Field representing a JavaFX property
        private String selected;

        private void setSelected(String selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        @Override
        protected Task<String> createTask() {
            return new Task<>() {

                // Task state should be immutable/encapsulated
                private final String selectedCopy = selected;

                @Override
                protected String call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        long waitTime = (long) (Math.random() * 15_000);
                        System.out.println("Waiting " + waitTime);
                        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                        return "You have selected item: " + selectedCopy;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Task interrupted!");
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

            };
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            System.out.println("Service succeeded.");
        }

        @Override
        protected void cancelled() {
            System.out.println("Service cancelled.");
        }

    }
}
```

When you call `Service.start()` it creates a `Task` and executes it using the current `Executor` contained in its [executor property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#executorProperty). If the property contains `null` then it uses some unspecified, default `Executor` (using daemon threads).

Above, you see I call [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#reset()) after cancelling and in the `onSucceeded` and `onFailed` callbacks. This is because a `Service` can only be started when in the `READY` [state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#stateProperty). You can use [`restart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#restart()) rather than `start()` if needed. It is basically equivalent to calling `cancel()`->`reset()`->`start()`.

<sup>1</sup>*The `Task` doesn't become resuable. Rather, the `Service` creates a new `Task` each time it's started.*

---

When you cancel a `Service` it cancels the currently running `Task`, if there is one. Even though the `Service`, and therefore `Task`, have been cancelled **does not mean that execution has actually stopped**. In Java, cancelling background tasks requires cooperation with the developer of said task.

This cooperation takes the form of periodically checking if execution should stop. If using a normal `Runnable` or `Callable` this would require checking the interrupted status of the current `Thread` or using some `boolean` flag<sup>2</sup>. Since `Task` extends [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) you can also use the `isCancelled()` method inherited from the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface. If you can't use `isCancelled()` for some reason (called outside code, not using a `Task`, etc...) then you check for thread interruption using:

- [`Thread.interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted())

  - Static method
  - Can only check current `Thread`
  - Clears the interruption status of current thread
- [`Thread.isInterrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted())

  - Instance method
  - Can check any `Thread` you have a reference to
  - Does not clear interruption status

*You can get a reference to the current thread via `Thread.currentThread()`*.

Inside your background code you'd want to check at appropriate points if the current thread has been interrupted, the `boolean` flag has been set, or the `Task` has been cancelled. If it has then you'd perform any necessary clean up and stop execution (either by returning or throwing an exception).

Also, if your `Thread` is waiting on some interruptible operation, such as blocking IO, then it will throw an `InterruptedException` when interrupted. In your MVCE you use `Thread.sleep` which is interruptible; meaning when you call cancel this method will throw the mentioned exception.

When I say "clean up" above I mean any clean up necessary *in the background* since you're still on the background thread. If you need to clean up anything on the FX thread (such as updating the UI) then you can use the `onCancelled` property of `Service`.

In the code above you'll also see I use the protected methods `succeeded()` and `cancelled()`. Both `Task` and `Service` provide these methods (as well as others for the various `Worker.State`s) and they will always be called on the FX thread. Read the documentation, however, as `ScheduledService` requires you to call the super implementations for some of these methods.

<sup>2</sup>*If using a `boolean` flag make sure updates to it are visible to other threads. You can do this by making it `volatile`, synchronizing it, or using a [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).*

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked perfectly! It did take a bit of work to adapt to a custom object (I created a new object to hold the individual data objects needed), but I like it. The other background tasks still execute, but since there are only 2 database queries, I can't cancel the first and the second is super fast anyway).

Comment: @Zephyr I'm glad I could help. I was actually just starting to answer your comments when you figured it out, but I'll give the highlights of what I was going to say anyway. (1) Remember the golden rule of JavaFX: _Never update the UI, directly or indirectly, from a thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread_, (2) It'd be preferable to have the input and output objects for the `Service` be immutable; but if they can't be then just make sure properly guard against multi-threading (maintain _happens-before_ relationships), (3) The `Task` should receive a copy of the input so state... (cont)

Comment: ... doesn't change while the `Task` is executing (when the input is immutable just copy the reference), and (4) I recommend keeping UI code separate from the `Service` unless its already an inner class of a controller. The obvious exception for this being what you do in the `setOnXXX` callbacks.

Comment: I am actually having the task create a new object and returning that. The input is just telling the task what query to run on the database and the new object is updated with that data.

Comment: Incidentally, are the `succeeded()` and `canceled()` methods within the `Service` necessary? Or is that just for cleanup, if needed?

Comment: @Zephyr I believe those `protected` methods are there more so you can do certain cleanup _inside_ the `Service`. For instance, `ScheduledService` uses some of them to update any properties needed then reschedule itself. Also, you could use the `failed()` method to always log a failure rather than having that behavior coded into `setOnFailed`. But no I don't believe they're necessary in your case. I mostly put them in my example to simply show they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`javafx.concurrent.Service.cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#cancel--) will cancel any currently running `Task`, making it throw an `InterruptedException`.

> *Cancels any currently running Task, if any. The state will be set to `CANCELLED`.*
>   <sub>[~ Service (JavaFX 8) - cancel ~](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#cancel--)</sub>

If additional cleanup is required one can provide [`Task.onCancelled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onCancelledProperty) event handler.

Comment: Given the MCVE in the original question, where would one call the `cancel()` method? Does each task need to be added to a list and then iterated over, cancelling all tasks?

Comment: It will only throw interrupted exception if the process is IO bound. There's no guarantee that in the real world that the worker task is in sleep state.

Answer (score 0):

**The demo class**

```
package com.changehealthcare.pid;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ThreadFun {
    public static ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    public static ServiceThread serviceThreads = new ServiceThread();
    public static Future futureService;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = "";

           while (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") == false) {
               line = in.readLine();
               //do something
               if (futureService != null) {
                   System.out.println("try to cancel");
                   futureService.cancel(true);
               }
               futureService = threadExecutor.submit(serviceThreads);
           }

           in.close();

    }
}
```

**The ServiceThread class**

```
package com.changehealthcare.pid;

public class ServiceThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("starting the service");

        boolean isResult = this.doStuff();

        if (isResult) {
            this.displayStuff();
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }

    private boolean doStuff() {
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("cancelled");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void displayStuff() {
        System.out.println("display done");
    }
}
```

Explaination
The demo application acts as a listener for System.in (keyboard). If any character pressed (with Enter), it will cancel any current thread if existing and submit a new one.

The Service Thread demo has a run() method which is calling doStuff() and displayStuff(). You can inject UI part for displayStuff. In the doStuff(), it is catching InterupptedException, if that exception happens, we don't perform displayStuff().

Please check and let see if it fits for your case. We can work out more.

Comment: In this case OP wants to eventually get the result of the thread back into the parent / draw thread. It would be more relevant to submit a `Callable<String>` instead of a `Runnable`. That way you end up with a `Future<String>` instead of a `Future<?>`

Comment: I am confused, though. Where does this allow me to cancel all previous tasks when a new one is started?

Comment: There is always max one previous task

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code that does what you need is this:

```
class SingleTaskRunner {

    private Task<?> lastTask = null; 

    void runTask(Task<?> task) {
        registerTask(task);
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    private synchronized void registerTask(Task<?> task) {
        if (lastTask != null) {
            lastTask.cancel(true);
        }
        lastTask = task;
    }
}
```

Note that it's quite similar to [Nghia Do's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353361/2032415), only with synchronization and without all this extra demo code.

You commented that you're confused how the mentioned answer allows you to cancel all previous tasks, but the fact is that - when you synchronize properly (like in `registerTask`) - you only need to store the last task because all previous tasks will already be cancelled (by the same `registerTask` method, which - due to being synchronized - will never execute concurrently). And as far as I know, calling `cancel` on a `Task` that has already completed is a no-op.

Moreover, using an `ExecutorService` over `new Thread(task).start()` (like Nghia Do proposed) is also a good idea, because [`Thread` creation is expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483105/2032415).

---

**EDIT**: I haven't given your MCVE a try before, sorry. Now that I have, and that I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior, I noticed the following flaws in your MCVE:

1. You're using [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) to simulate calculations, but calling [`Future.cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) when inside `Thread.sleep()` terminates the task immediately because [`Future.cancel()` calls `Thread.interrupt()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627037/2032415) inside, and `Thread.sleep()` checks for interruption flag, which you most likely don't do in your real code.
2. You're assigning the result of the calculation to a private field. Since (as mentioned above) the calculation **was** interrupted in your original MCVE immediately, and probably **wasn't** interrupted in your real code, in your real code the value of the field could get overwritten by an already canceled task.
3. I believe that in your real code, you probably do more than just assining the result to the field. In the original MCVE, I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior even after replacing `Thread.sleep()` with a loop. The reason for this is that the `onSucceeded` handler does **not** get called, when the task was canceled (which is good). I believe, though, that in your real code, you may have done something more important (like some GUI update) in `Task.call()` than what you've shown in MCVE, because otherwise, as far as I understand, you wouldn't have experienced the original problem.

Here's a modification of your MCVE that should **not** exhibit the original problem.

*EDIT*: I further modified the MCVE to print cancelation info and also print times of events. This code, however, does not reproduce the behavior the OP wrote about.

```
public class TaskRace extends Application {

    private final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    private final Label label = new Label("Nothing selected");
    private final SingleTaskRunner runner = new SingleTaskRunner();

    private final long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Simple UI
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, label);

        // Populate the ListView
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
        );


        // Add listener to the ListView to start the task whenever an item is selected
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (newValue != null) {
                // Create the background task
                MyTask task = new MyTask();

                // Update the label when the task is completed
                task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                    label.setText(task.getValue());
                    println("Assigned " + task.selectedItem);
                });
                task.setOnCancelled(event -> println("Cancelled " + task.selectedItem));

                runner.runTask(task);
            }

        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

    }

    private void println(String string) {
        System.out.format("%5.2fs: %s%n", 0.001 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis), string);
    }

    private class MyTask extends Task<String> {

        final String selectedItem = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        @Override
        protected String call() {
            int ms = new Random().nextInt(10000);
            println(String.format("Will return %s in %.2fs", selectedItem, 0.001 * ms));

            // Do long-running task (takes random time)
            long limitMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + ms;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < limitMillis) {
            }

            println("Returned " + selectedItem);
            return "You have selected item: " + selectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to make any difference. In my MCVE above, I have replaced the `new Thread(task).start();` line with `runner.runTask(task);` and `runner` is an instance of your `SingleTaskRunner` class. The result is the same as the original question.

Comment: I am confused, again. Other than using a loop instead of `Thread.sleep()`, what changes did you make and why did that work? I can't update my actual program to simply use a loop...

Comment: @Zephyr I'll try to explain. Point 1 concerned the problem with **verifiability** in your *MCVE* (so you absolutely don't have to introduce any loop to your real code). Points 2 and 3 concerned both MCVE and your real code - if, in your real code, you do any *state modifications* to the `Application` instance inside `Task.call()` (in your MCVE, you do it by mutating `labelValue`), please, try to move them to `Task.setOnSucceeded`, and try to use `Task.getValue()` for transferring the calculation result *from* `Task.call()` *to* your `Application` (instead of mutating `Application`s state).

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I still have the issue. In fact, in my real app, the tasks never get cancelled and I'm not sure why. I see that `lastTask.cancel()` IS being executed, but my `onCancelled()` method is not. The `onSucceeded()` method is always executed.

Comment: You may check the return value of `lastTask.cancel()` (debugger's your friend here). Probably it's `false`, which means the task has not been canceled because it has already completed. I don't know, maybe you're delegating your computations to some other thread, and the task completes immediately? Until you provide an MCVE that reflects the complexity of your real code much closer, it'll be difficult to help, because it'd involve too much guessing. PS. I updated the modified MCVE in my answer to also print cancelation info. You might try to adapt it further to become more like your real code.

Answer (score 0):

If, for whatever reason, you are unable to make it work in your real use case using cancelation-based solutions (cf. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356093/2032415), [Slaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434068/2032415), and actually all the other answers), there's one more thing you may try.

The solution proposed here is theoretically **worse** than any cancelation-based one (because all the redundant calculations will continue until done, thus wasting resources). However, practically, a working solution will be better than a non-working one (provided that it works for you, and that it's the **only** one that does - so please check [Slaw's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434068/2032415) first).

---

I propose that you forgo cancelation completely, and instead use a simple [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) field to store the value of the last selected item:

```
private volatile String lastSelectedItem = null;
```

Upon selecting a new label, you would update this field:

```
lastSelectedItem = task.selectedItem;
```

Then, in the on-succeeded event, you would simply check whether you're allowed to assign the result of the computation:

```
if (task.selectedItem.equals(lastSelectedItem))
```

Find the entire modified MCVE below:

```
public class TaskRaceWithoutCancelation extends Application {

    private final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    private final Label label = new Label("Nothing selected");

    private final long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private volatile String lastSelectedItem = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Simple UI
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, label);

        // Populate the ListView
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
        );


        // Add listener to the ListView to start the task whenever an item is selected
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (newValue != null) {
                // Create the background task
                MyTask task = new MyTask();
                lastSelectedItem = task.selectedItem;

                // Update the label when the task is completed
                task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                    if (task.selectedItem.equals(lastSelectedItem)) {
                        label.setText(task.getValue());
                        println("Assigned " + task.selectedItem);
                    }
                });

                new Thread(task).start();
            }

        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

    }

    private void println(String string) {
        System.out.format("%5.2fs: %s%n", 0.001 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis), string);
    }

    private class MyTask extends Task<String> {

        final String selectedItem = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        @Override
        protected String call() {
            int ms = new Random().nextInt(10000);
            println(String.format("Will return %s in %.2fs", selectedItem, 0.001 * ms));

            // Do long-running task (takes random time)
            long limitMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + ms;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < limitMillis) {
            }

            println("Returned " + selectedItem);
            return "You have selected item: " + selectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```