# Interrupts handling in java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

When we are talking about interrupts in java, say, `Thread.sleep(1000);` it might throw an exception only if it's been called `t.interrupt()` or also for potential interruptions sent by the OS?

Comment: Note that some frameworks such as ExecutorServices can call interrupt in some circumstances (task cancellation, shutdown...). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126997/who-is-calling-the-java-thread-interrupt-method-if-im-not

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java 7 language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.3):

> Interruption actions occur upon invocation of `Thread.interrupt`, as well as methods defined to invoke it in turn, such as `ThreadGroup.interrupt`.

There is no mention of external factors being able to interrupt a thread.

Comment: mm.. What if the the OS needs to do something critical and need CPU in that moment? would not send an interrupt to the current thread(without terminating it)?

Comment: No. It just deschedules the entire process. Thread interruption has nothing to do with either thread scheduling or process scheduling.

Comment: Unfortunately, the word 'Interrupt' is overloaded.  It was bad choice for this Java functionality since drivers and OS had already had this word 'booked up' for decades.

Comment: @MartinJames ok thanks a lot I thought it was the same thing! it's just an overloading. damn!