# I received InterruptedException while Thread.interrupted is not called

Tags: java, multithreading

I am in a situation where I catch an`InterruptedException` but I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the `Thread.interrupt()` method and there is no hit.

What else can cause `InterruptedException` to be thrown? Note that I encounter this problem only on Windows, the same code runs fine on Linux. As the interrupt method delegates to a native call interrupt0, I guess it comes from there. But how can I investigate further ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I found my problem. It was also my misunderstanding of the interrupt mechanism. Thread.interrupt is called indeed. What bit me is that it is called long before I start the wait(). But as the thread has the interrupt flag activated, the first call to wait throws the exception immediately.

In my case, it was log4j who set the interrupted flag when it tries to create a NonBlockingSocketAppender on an invalid address. Even weird is that it interrupts the thread it is currently running on...

Comment: show your code...so we can better help you....

Comment: Some good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126997/who-is-calling-the-java-thread-interrupt-method-if-im-not

Comment: You sure it is throwing `InterruptedException`?

Comment: what shows up in the stacktrace for the InterruptedException?

Comment: @CPU100 Well I have 100k lines of code including Spring framework and other thirdparty libraries so I don't know what to show...

Comment: @NathanHughes The stack trace only shows the thread that has been interrupted, no details of what caused the exception...

Comment: @Gray Thanks for the link. I did not find it in my search. It is throwing an InterruptedException. That's the only type of my catch block

Comment: A possible issue is that the debugger is not able to put a breakpoint in the thread interrupt code.  So although someone is calling `thread.interrupt()` the debugger is missing it.