# Implementation of addShutdownHook

Tags: java

Where and how to implement addShutdownHook in a class, which have no main method? Can this used to kill all the active sockets initialized by that class?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722826/when-do-i-need-to-call-this-method-runtime-getruntime-addshutdownhook   
It's not really a duplicate but I think you can learn things there?
Also: http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.se/2010/11/runtimeaddshutdownhook.html

Comment: @SamuelÅslund: Thanks for your help.. I have searched for it but didn't got this link..

Comment: @SamuelÅslund: addShutdownHook doesn't work when we kill the server  in linux using Kill -9 command. Any other solution for the same??

Comment: Nope, the whole point of kill -9 is that the program killed is not allowed to do anything at all before it dies. To learn more about the kill command "signal" and "kill" may be good google keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Might work for you,

```
   public class AddShutdownHookSample {
      public void attachShutDownHook(){
           Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                      System.out.println("Inside Add Shutdown Hook");
                }
           });

           System.out.println("Shut Down Hook Attached.");
      }
   }
```

And in main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AddShutdownHookSample sample = new AddShutdownHookSample();
  sample.attachShutDownHook();
  System.out.println("Last instruction of Program....");
  System.exit(0);
 }
```

> Describe whole thing that you are trying to do and show the very exact point where you are having trouble this would be easier for other to help you.

Comment: @Atmaram I couldnot got you, do you mean that can we do the same on other static functions. Then the answer is YES.

Comment: I was saying that if I add this part of the code in static block of our class.. Will it work?

Comment: Done Like this...                                                                                                                    static { Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook (
     new Thread() {
      public void run() {
       server.shutdown();
      }
     }
   ); }

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example, this may help you

```
public class RuntimeDemo {

   // a class that extends thread that is to be called when program is exiting
 static class Message extends Thread {

  public void run() {
     System.out.println("Bye.");
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

     // register Message as shutdown hook
     Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Message());

     // print the state of the program
     System.out.println("Program is starting...");

     // cause thread to sleep for 3 seconds
     System.out.println("Waiting for 3 seconds...");
     Thread.sleep(3000);

     // print that the program is closing 
     System.out.println("Program is closing...");


  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done like this...

```
 static { 
         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook ( new Thread() { 
               public void run() { 
                   server.shutdown(); 
               } 
          } ); 
  }
```