# Do I need to close PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I'm writing a simple Swing GUI which includes a text field which prints debug messages and exceptions. I currently have it set up where I write to a PipedOutputStream, and I have a daemon thread which reads from the connected PipedInputStream and writes to the text area.

While I was trying to figure out how to close the stream in my daemon thread, I came across [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498388/2388930) which says that daemon threads should not hold any resources. Do piped streams count? Do they need to be closed?

Comment: You should close anything that is closeable.

Comment: @EJP The reason I asked the question is because I don't know how to do this. I don't believe daemon threads have defined shutdown behaviour? I think you can add shutdown hooks, but if this was important, I feel like it would be baked in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `PipedInputStream` / `PipedOutputStream` do not hold any *operating system* resources.  So any advice that says that daemon threads should not hold resources does not apply here.  (But see below!)

However, this doesn't mean that you don't *ever* need to `close()` (at least) the `PipedOutputStream`.  Depending on your application, the corresponding `PipedInputStream` *may* need the pipeline to be closed to complete its work.

---

Regarding the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498388/2388930):

After looking at the Answer and the comments, I think that his argument is an over-generalization:

- He is correct that anything (daemon thread or whatever) that has lots (he says "hundreds") of resources open at the same time is a bad idea.
- He is also correct in saying that doing *critical* file updates in a daemon thread is risky.  But doing *critical* file updates in *any* thread in Java has the same risk<sup>1</sup>.  Or in C.  You just need to design the update sequence to be fail-safe ... or rely on something like DB transactions for fail-safety.

However, it is not logically sound (or pragmatically sensible) to generalise this to saying that daemon threads shouldn't hold resources.  Clearly there are use-cases where the above concerns do not apply.

---

<sup>1 - The application may get a "kill -9" which will cause it to exit immediately *without* running the shutdown hooks.  The application may get a "file system full" in the middle of the critical update.  The power may go off.  And so on ...</sup>