# getting the number of threads in a Java VM using Java code

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to get the number of threads in a JAVA VM, using JAVA code. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can extrapolate it from this [Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1323408/811865)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces().size()
```

Comment: By doing that you retrieve the stacktrace of every running Thread. That could be annoyingly slow if you had hundreds of threads, see [Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1323408/811865)

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can also get it using JMX using [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) management interface. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm) is a sample.

Comment: ThreadMSBean.getThreadCount() should be more efficient than getting all the stack traces.