# How to catch exception thrown by another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I'm using a library that creates its own thread and it throws an exception. How can I catch that exception? The exception is thrown on the line marked below:

```
ResourceDescriptor rd = new ResourceDescriptor();
        rd.setWsType(ResourceDescriptor.TYPE_FOLDER);
        fullUri += "/" + token;
        System.out.println(fullUri);
        // >>> EXCEPTION THROWN ON THE FOLLOWING LINE <<<
        rd.setUriString(fullUri.replaceAll("_", ""));
        try{
            rd = server.getWSClient().get(rd, null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(e.getMessage().contains("resource was not found")){
                this.addFolder(fullUri, label, false);
                System.out.println("Folder does not exist, will be added now.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error Messages: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you call the method that throws an exeption? (And may be: How do know an exception is thrown?)

Comment: I already try to catch the generic Exception class, but I still get Exception thrown. I googled it and it seems to be thrown by another thread from the library I'm using. The library interacts with a web application through web services.

Answer (score 22):

If you can not catch it maybe that helps you:

If you have the `Thread` object you can try to set a [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).
Take a look at [Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).

Give us some more detail about the library you use and how you use it.

Comment: +1 I did not know about this. This is better than my answer.

Comment: I do not have any control over the thread created by that library I'm using, so I can't explicitly set uncaught exception handler on their threads. What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java). That way you _could_ get a hold of the `Thread` object ;) It is of course not really a clean solution but worth a try.

Comment: And what if I catch the exception? How can I access it ( maybe from an agent)?

Answer (score 7):

If all you have is a `Thread` object then there is no way to catch any exceptions (which I assume are `RuntimeException`).  The proper way to do this is by using the `Future<?>` class used by the `ExecutorService` but you don't have control over the code starting the `Thread` I assume.

If you are providing the `Runnable` or if you are injecting any of the code into the library, then you could wrap it in a class that catches and holds the `Exception` for you but that is only if the exception is in your code or is thrown from within code you are calling.  Something like the following:

```
final AtomicReference<Exception> exception = new AtomicReference<Exception>();
Thread thread = library.someMethod(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      try {
         // call a bunch of code that might throw
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // store our exception thrown by the inner thread
         exception.set(e);
      }
   }
});
// we assume the library starts the thread
// wait for the thread to finish somehow, maybe call library.join()
thread.join();
if (exception.get() != null) {
   throw exception.get();
}
```

Also, if you are forking your own thread you can also set the uncaught exception handler:

```
thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
   public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
      // log it, dump it to the console, or ...
   }
});
```

But if the thread code inside of the library cannot be wrapped by you then that won't work.  If you edit your question and show some code and provide some more details, I can edit my question to provide better help.

Comment: If you're providing a `Thread` and not a `Runnable`, you can override the `join` methods.  This would allow you to check if the thread exited with an exception and re-throw the exception in the joining-thread's context.

Comment: @artbristol You're right. That's unfortunate.

Comment: Currently I have no control over the library as it is compiled already.

Comment: Great explanation. Could you elaborate on how using a `Future` can help?

Comment: `Future` allows you to use an executor service but still get the exceptions thrown by the thread in the pool @flow2k.