# In java how can I catch an exception thrown from child thread and then throw it again from the parent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, io

I currently have the following sample code that I am trying to convert OutputStream to InputStream, which I got the idea from `Method 2` in http://blog.ostermiller.org/convert-java-outputstream-inputstream

But my question here is, the save method could throw IOException, and I would like to catch that and re-throw that as part of this getInputStream method.

I am trying to wrap the IOException thrown by save(out) to a runtime exception, but I know that this runtime exception cannot be caught by the parent thread. So I am stuck on this, can anyone point me some directions?

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run () {
            try {
                save(out); // this save method can throw IOException
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save entries to output stream", e);
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    return in;
}


private void save(OutputStream out) throws IOException {...}
```

---

I have read [How to catch an Exception from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread) but felt my question is still different,
because I want to re-throw the exception in parent thread, the question above solves the problem that catches the exception only

Comment: Possible duplicate, check answers here, especially second one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351926/how-to-catch-exception-thrown-by-another-thread-in-java

Comment: It feels like you're duplicating the machinery of `Future`, `Callable` and `ExecutorService`.  I'd like to know why those don't work for you before trying to re-invent them.

Comment: @markspace thx for pointing out these, I am new to multi-threading, let me dig into those concepts a bit!

Comment: Basically, `Runnable` doesn't throw exceptions, but `Callable` does (it's the new improved `Runnable`) and if you pass a Callable to an ExecutorService you get back a Future that does the work of passing any exception back to you.

Comment: @markspace, Better to say that the `Runnable` interface and the classes that use it were not designed with exceptions in mind.  In fact, a Runnable object's `run()` method _can_ throw unchecked exceptions and other `Throwable` objects, and that is the reason why every `Thread` has to have an [uncaught exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler).

Comment: Threads have no parents or children.

Answer (score 1):

> But my question here is, the save method could throw IOException, and I would like to catch that and re-throw that as part of this getInputStream method.

You can't do that, because an exception can be raised in the background thread executing `save()` long after `getInputStream()` returns.

If `save()` can throw an exception for some reason other than an `IOException` from its `PipedOutputStream`, and you want to convey some information about that failure to the thread that is reading from the `PipedInputStream`, submitting a `Callable` to an `ExecutorService` is probably the right approach. An example of this case would be that `save()` queries a database, and writes the results to a stream; if query fails, you want to log that `SQLException` *in the thread that is reading that stream.* The reading thread could read the `PipedInputStream`, and then check the `Future` it received from submitting the task to the `ExecutorService` to see if it completed abnormally.

But if you don't need any information from the exception thrown by `save()`, and just want to throw an exception in the thread reading from the corresponding `PipedInputStream`, simply let the background thread die. This will raise a "broken pipe" `IOException` in the main thread when it attempts to read from its `PipedInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

While all the comments that lead to uncaught exception handler and similar stuff are correct, I would like to post this answer as an alternative.

You can use an ExecutorService which will return you a Future and then you can catch ExecutionException when getting the result, something like this (typing directly here, might need some validation):

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future result = pool.submit(this::save);
result.get(); // will throw ExecutionException
```

Comment: Thx! one more bit, save(out) method here will throw IOException, so Runnable is not fit here, we need to wrap that with Callable instead.