# detecting instance of another thread from outside spawning thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread, `A`, which performs periodic actions inside a `while(running)` loop. I then have another thread,`B`, which listens for user input. When the user presses a button, thread `B` spawns a new thread to perform a task (let's call it an instance of Thread `C`). This task involves sending information over the internet and can take up to 20 seconds. There can be more than one instance of `C` active at once.

The problem I am having is this. I would like thread `A` to only run it's code if there are no threads of type 'C' currently active. To be more clear, thread A looks something like this:

```
 class ThreadA extends Thread{

      public void run(){
            while(running){
                performAction();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
      }
 }
```

If an instance of `C` is detected, then obviously I would not like `performAction()` to be called. If the thread is currently executing `performAction()`, then I would like to stop its execution at its current progress.

I'm not sure how to proceed, as I'm not sure how I would obtain a reference of the spawned threads from inside thread A.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1323480/187492) shows you how to loop through a list of running threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.lang.ThreadGroup`.  By constructing all instances of ThreadC with a static ThreadGroup, you can maintain all of the instances of ThreadC and get a count of the active ones using `ThreadGroup#activeCount()`.  Simply add a condition in ThreadA to only invoke performAction() if your `public static ThreadC.threadGroup` field returns 0 when activeCount() is called upon it.