# SWT - Is there a way to show running threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java)

This is just for testing purposes - not production UI

Is it possible to set something like a button on my Application's base dialog that when clicks would System Print the current running threads?

Something like below

```
   Button showThreadsButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
   pdfButton.setText("Show Running Threads");
   pdfButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          String test = Display.getThreads().toString();
          System.out.println("Running Threads " + test + "\n);
       }
   });
```

I am not sure if all my threads are disposing like they should be.

Comment: You can run your code with a debugger to see how your threads are behaving.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstack from the command line to dump threads.
Then you don't need to worry about it leaking into your production code.

jstack is part of the jvm.