# Finding an Instance of a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to find out if an instance of a certain thread is running and so i can use it. Is this possible and how do i do that? Any strategies or suggestions?

For example say i have this thread:

```
public class SomeThread extends Thread{
      ArrayList<String> stringArray=new ArrayList<String>();
      public void run(){
      //some long time operation or messaging going on
     }
     public ArrayList<String> getList(){
     return stringArray;
    }

}

public abstract class AnyActivity{
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                if(//any an instace of SomeThread exist){
                ArrayList<String> array=//somehow.getList();
                } else {
                SomeThread thread=new SomeThread();
                thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                thread.start();

        }

}
```

**Edit 1:** I don't want to pass a reference of the thread because this might be the only place i start it.Think as SomeThread has major importance and starts with the application. I need to ask it to something via `Messenger`'s or it might tell the activity to do something in the same way.I have updated the example code and set the AnyActivity abstract.All the activities in the application extends this class so i don't know if the thread has been created and started before which means i can't rely on references.

So i cant work with `thread.isAlive()` and there is no static method `SomeThread.isAlive()`. I cound use `setName()` inside the thread but how can i find it afterwards by its name?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks for the guidance

```
private SomeThread getSomeThread(){
    Thread thread=null;
    int i=0;

    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
    while(thread==null && i<threadArray.length){
        if(threadArray[i].getName().equals(SomeThread.class.getSimpleName()))
            thread=threadArray[i];
        i++;
    }

    return (SomeThread)thread;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference of the Thread you are interested in later/further to you code and then test it with :

```
  Thread t; t.isAlive();
```

P.S. You could tell use exactly what you want to do and probably we can help you more.

Comment: i can't pass a reference, i have updated my question can you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

`thread.isAlive()` is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive()

Answer (score 0):

try this

[Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java)

you can also get a thread by its name or id

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/java_tip_how_list_and_find_threads_and_thread_groups#Gettingathreadbyname

Answer (score 0):

```
 if( SomeThread.isAlive())
 {
       // in running state 
 }
```

[isAlive(](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29)) method returns true if it is running else false