# List of currently running threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I was looking for a solution to get the amount of threads running in my program.
I ended up with this two solutions from [Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java).

Using

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
runningThreads = threadSet.size();
```

I end up with **75** threads.

---

Using

```
ThreadGroup rootGroup = Thread.currentThread( ).getThreadGroup( );
ThreadGroup parentGroup;
while ( ( parentGroup = rootGroup.getParent() ) != null ) {
        rootGroup = parentGroup;
}
Thread[] threads = new Thread[ rootGroup.activeCount() ];
while ( rootGroup.enumerate( threads, true ) == threads.length ) {
        threads = new Thread[ threads.length * 2 ];
}
runningThreads = threads.length;
```

I end up with the exact doubled amount of threads -> **150**

---

I was wondering why the theads are doubled and saw this `threads = new Thread[ threads.length * 2 ];`.

Why do we multiply with 2 in this method?

EDIT:
Maybe I have malformed my question. Even if it is answered right now I want to correct it.
The question is why we multiply with 2 even the size is already big enough and therefor get the wrong amount of currently running threads.

Comment: I don't know, it's your method. You tell us. EDIT: Ah, I see it's from the referenced answer. Looks like it's to expand the array's capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation of ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html), the method

```
public int enumerate(Thread[] list,
            boolean recurse)
```

will recursively enumerate the subgroups. However, it only returns as many threads that can be filled in `list` argument.  So, the code tries to allocate more size to list if it observes that you have received exactly `length` elements in the `list` with the assumption that there were more threads to enumerate but array size was not sufficient.

So, when loop terminates, even if you have `length` elements in the `list`, last few elements will be null and you will have to ignore them while determining thread count