# Main method 5th priority , which are the threads which are having higher priority that main method in java

Tags: java

We know that if we execute the `getcurrentthread.priority` method we will get the thread priority as 5. I am not able to get the answer for the threads having priority higher than the Main method.

Comment: Please edit your question with more of what you want. It's not clear

Comment: Actually it's quite clear what he asked. You just have to read it twice :)

Comment: On a side note, I fail to imagine what a reasonable use case for this would be. Possibly, you are heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that this is somehow the index of the thread in a priority queue, and that therefore at least 4 other threads must exist.
Well, this isn't the case, it's **not an index** but a **value used to compare its priority with other concurrent threads**, not only in your VM but also on your system. In fact, threads can have the same priority.

**Side note:** when setting the priorities on Threads, always use the **constants** `MIN_PRIORITY`, `NORM_PRIORITY` and `MAX_PRIORITY`. If you need intermediate values, calcuate them using the constants:

```
int mediumHighPriority = (Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)/2;
```

The constant values may get changed in the future (could have a wider range, or even be reversed so that lower number equals higher priority, or the NORM_PRIORITY could get lower or higher), if you use the constants rather than their value you're on the save side and the code gets more legible.

Comment: Thanks Peter. can u elaborate on this. at least 4 other threads must exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all threads in the current program via [ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html), see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323480/1015327).

Answer (score 0):

When a java application is started, the JVM creates the main ThreadGroup as a member of the system ThreadGroup and set the priority to default(i.e NORM_PRIORITY).

This only applies to the threads in the current Java program though and will not provide any information about all the other threads running in other processes in the OS.