# Wait for mail sending in another thread to complete

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail

I've got a problem I can't really figure out. I have my main thread, and in it I want to

1. Send an email with an attachment
2. Delete the files that were attached

in that order. My problem is that I am using an email helper that I don't have control over, and it generates another thread that does the sending. Because of this, **my files are being deleted before they are done being attached**, and I am getting a FNF error in the mailer. I am looking to find a way to make my main thread wait until the files are done being attached. I don't know how long that will take. I don't have control over the other thread creation, so I can't use `join()`. Is there something I can use with `Transport` maybe, or a way to wait for all threads made in a method/class to stop?

The layout of my program is

```
//do stuff
MailHelper.sendMail(...); //thread is created somewhere in this method
deleteFiles(); //this happens before sendMail is finished!
```

I need to use Java 6. Worst-case I can have my main thread sleep for a few seconds, but that's unideal. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does MailHelper give you any indication that sending is finished? Can you attach a listener?

Comment: No it doesn't. I can't modify the class at all either

Comment: How can you tell the mail is sent? Do you have any way to check?

Comment: Can you really not modify the method so that it returns a ``Future<?>``?

Comment: sounds like you're out of luck, use a better mail sender

Comment: As far as I can tell there's nothing that would indicate it's done...the method that's called starts a new thread, in which it calls `Transport.send()`, then exits. No kind of status variables or anything

Comment: what types of objects are you passing to `sendMail()`?

Comment: It spawns a thread out of nowhere? You should use an other API!

Comment: I agree, it really isn't a great API, but I'm restricted to it. I pass `sendMail()` a message, subject, and attachment path. The class has all other info needed. Thanks for the input but it looks like I'm just going to have the thread sleep for a while...it's an automated process so hopefully it won't hurt too much.

Comment: @KevinWalters I second to sjr. You need your own implementation of send mail if you want execute sequentially those things.

Comment: Hey guys, I've been thinking and might have a solution - what if I made a new `ThreadGroup`, made a new thread for calling `sendMail()`, and put that thread in the thread group. Then I'd do a join on that thread - after that thread finishes, the new thread I am trying to wait for will have been created, so I would get all threads in that `ThreadGroup`, and join on all of them - then when they're all done, I can continue! Does this sound reasonable? I've never used `ThreadGroup` before so my reasoning may be off.

Comment: As an extreme measure, you might try by holding a `Reference` (`java.lang.ref`) to the path argument in your thread and delete the file after the reference has been queued... it's hard to tell whether it will work without the source of your `MailSender`... `MailSender` could use it to construct some other object (`java.io.File`?) and the string could be garbage-collected before the mail has been sent. If it works, however, it will probably be one of the dirtiest hacks in history...

Comment: If by "automated process" you mean the JVM exits after the emails are sent (and with enough disk space to hold all attachments in the batch), you might just use `deleteOnExit` (`java.io.File`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question! Basically you want to wait for all child threads to complete, but have no control over them.

Here is a demonstration of the technique using [`ThreadGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html):

Assuming you have a `MailHelper` class like this:

```
public class MailHelper {

    public void sendMail(){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("MailHelper: Sending mail for 6s");
                for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(".");
                }
                System.out.println("MailHelper: Sent mail!");
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

}
```

then our `Main` class demonstrates how use it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final MailHelper mh = new MailHelper();

        ThreadGroup mailThreadGroup = new ThreadGroup("mailGroup");
        Thread callSendmailThread = new Thread(mailThreadGroup, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Calling sendMail().");
                mh.sendMail();
                System.out.println("sendMail() returned.");
            }
        });
        callSendmailThread.start();
        callSendmailThread.join();
        System.out.println("callSendmailThread joined. Waiting for rest of ThreadGroup to finish.");

        // We cannot rely on ThreadGroup.activeCount() to give us an accurate number, and it could be zero!
        Thread[] mailThreads = new Thread[mailThreadGroup.activeCount() + 1];
        //Therefore retry enumerate until our array was large enough to hold all
        while ( mailThreadGroup.enumerate( mailThreads, true ) == mailThreads.length ) {
            mailThreads = new Thread[ mailThreads.length * 2 ];
        }

        for(Thread t : mailThreads){
            if(t != null && t.isAlive()){
                System.out.println("Joining thread " + t.getName());
                t.join();
                System.out.println("Thread " + t.getName() + " joined.");
            }
        }
        mailThreadGroup.destroy();
        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
}
```

The output:

```
Calling sendMail().
sendMail() returned.
callSendmailThread joined. Waiting for rest of ThreadGroup to finish.
Joining thread Thread-1
MailHelper: Sending mail for 6s
.
.
.
.
.
.
MailHelper: Sent mail!
Thread Thread-1 joined.
Done!
```

Note that you **must** ensure that the `Thread-1` is actually started by the time you enumerate the ThreadGroup, thus joining the `callSendMailThread` is absolutely necessary. Otherwise you'd get a race condition.

Also note that the [quirky behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323480/202504) of `ThreadGroup.enumerate()` must be accounted for, by retrying to enumerate all the items several times.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing, I just forgot to post my final solution, good answer!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve the issue logically is to track if the mail is send sucessfully.
It can be done by any of the below
1) Set a global variable with some value after mail is send from other thread and reset it value once the attachement is deleted.
2) Instead of variable you can also try creating a file.

Thank you,
Mukeshkoshym

Comment: I never liked global variables.