# How to read all Thread Name, Running on JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to read the threads generated by other programs, which are running in the same JVM.
I used the following code:

```
long a[] = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getAllThreadIds();
ThreadInfo[] thInfo = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadInfo(a);
for(int i=0;i<thInfo.length;i++)
    System.out.println(thInfo[i].getThreadName());
```

but without the expected success.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java

Comment: Please define "expected success" and "other programs". Note that if you start a new java application you'll start a new and independent JVM instance which you can't get the threads of.

Comment: "Other programs running in the same JVM"? Normally you have one JVM instance per program (unless you're talking about web applications running in a servlet container, for example).

Comment: I wanted to know how to get all the names and status of the threads that are running on my server.
Thank you