# Can I detect a leaked thread in a Junit test?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got some code that forgets to set the daemon flag on a thread. Thus, `main` methods don't ever complete. I'll track it down eventually, but I wonder: is there any way to reflectively notice the existence of non-daemon threads so that a JUnit (or testng, or whatever) test could complain in this case? Note that these test frameworks orchestrate `System.exit` so that the excess threads don't manifest as hangs.

Comment: How would you want this reported?  Just that such a thread exists, or some sort of pin-point on where the thread was created?

Comment: Just its existence. ThreadMXBean does not show the daemon flag, if it did, that would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all running threads ([Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java)):

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

Then you can iterate through the list in some test that you write calling `Thread.isDaemon()`.  You'll probably need to throw out some threads that correspond to the JVM or the JUnit framework, but that's probably doable by checking other aspects of the threads, like their name.