# java process hangs, how can I check what it is doing?

Tags: java, debugging

When I program in C++, I use GDB for debugging.

I can check the states of the multiple threads and which code lines they are executing.

How can I check what each java process is working on?

Comment: Are you using an IDE and have access to source code? you can get memory dump and thread dump also using java standard libs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a List of all Threads currently running in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java)

Comment: For Java 7+ you can use Java Mission Control, older versions use Java VisualVM. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html