# Walk a chain of objects recursively in functional style

Tags: java, functional-programming, tail-recursion, vavr

A common looping pattern in imperative coding styles is to follow a chain of objects to find the end, e.g.:

```
private ThreadGroup rootOf(ThreadGroup leaf) {
  ThreadGroup rootGroup = leaf;
  ThreadGroup parentGroup;
  while ((parentGroup = rootGroup.getParent()) != null) {
    rootGroup = parentGroup;
  }
  return rootGroup;
}
```

(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323480/27358))

I feel like there must be a standard functional pattern that's logically equivalent to this, but I'm not sure what it is. I've come up with the recursive method below using [Vavr's `Option`](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_option):

```
private ThreadGroup rootOf(ThreadGroup leaf) {
  return Option.of(leaf.getParent()) // returns None for null
    .map(this::rootOf)
    .getOrElse(leaf);
}
```

But it seems as though there ought to be a way to do it without explicit recursion, especially in a language like Java without tail call optimization (I'm imagining something vaguely analogous to `foldLeft()` but on an iteratively computed value stream, if that makes any sense?)

What's the standard functional approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream.iterate + filtering should do it:

```
Stream.iterate(leaf, ThreadGroup::getParent)
    .filter(g -> g.getParent() == null)
    .findFirst().get();
```

Comment: And this works because the filter ensures we only iterate till we reach the root, and then stop before we NPE?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how.

Comment: Throws a NoSuchElementException if the tree is empty. Possibly replace ```.findFirst().get()``` with ```.headOption()``` and possibly add ```.filter(Objects::nonNull)```?