# Can I figure out if a given thread has been started by this thread or a descendant of this thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

Context: I want to add a log `Handler` to the root logger in order to collect all logging output from a task. During task execution, other threads might get created. I want their log output, too.

Some of those threads are created by methods of libraries, like Ant for example.

Currently my log handler checks the current `Thread` in the `publish` method, and stores the record if it is the same as the original task thread. But I miss the log messages of the threads spawned by the task thread.

Just going by start/stop time doesn't work either because multiple tasks are running concurrently, each with their own potential child-threads.

Comment: You could always extend the `Thread` class and require a parent thread in the constructor, then use a getter.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over thread creation that happens in the used libraries.

Comment: Does it? I have to check if my eclipse does this as well.

Comment: If you have control of the initial thread, you can create it in a new `ThreadGroup`, since most threads by default are created in the same group as their "parent" thread, and then use the `ThreadGroup` for you logging filter. However, this won't work if a library creates a thread in a specific thread group, and it won't work if a library uses a thread pool, so you might be out of luck.

Comment: @CardinalSystem looks like my eclipse shows just a flat list of threads in the debugger.

Comment: @Andreas that's interesting, and would already be a nice improvement over the current situation. I will try that immediately.

Comment: @CardinalSystem I don't know what that means. It's a web application running inside tomcat. At application/server startup I start a scheduler thread, which in turn starts a nightly backup task for each of several subsystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thread instance has a [`ThreadGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) within it. The thread groups form a tree in which every thread group except the initial thread group has a parent. Using this information, we can apply the [`ThreadGroup#parentOf(ThreadGroup)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#parentOf(java.lang.ThreadGroup)) method to check if the current thread is the parent of the given thread:

```
// potentialParent would probably just be Thread.currentThread();
public static boolean isChild(Thread potentialChild, Thread potentialParent) {
    try {
        return potentialParent.getThreadGroup().parentOf(potentialChild.getThreadGroup());
    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some IDEs will show every running thread if you use the debugger. Take [Eclipse's Debug View](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-showsystemthreads.htm) for example. Each thread in your program appears as a node in the tree:

[image: Debug View]

If you want to take a step further and do some dirty work, you could use reflection to access the threads stored in given thread group, but I dissuade you from taking such measures:

```
// There is a thread array field in the ThreadGroup class.
Field f = ThreadGroup.class.getDeclaredField("threads");
// The 'threads' field has no access modifiers.
f.setAccessible(true);

Thread[] threads = (Thread[]) f.get(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup());
/*
 * Search 'threads' accordingly...
 */
```

You can also play around a bit with [`ThreadUtils.getAllThreadGroups()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/ThreadUtils.html#getAllThreadGroups--) if you happen to have [Appache commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) on your build path.

Comment: Thank you, sounds fantastic. I am implementing and testing this right now. Also, which IDE do you use that shows the thread hierarchy?

Comment: Looks like it's working :). I am also setting a custom ThreadGroup for my backup tasks now. Thanks again.

Comment: @RetoHöhener I didn't see your second comment until now (2yrs later). Happy things are working out for you. If you are interested in learning a little more, take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018672/5645656).