# How can I stop thread containing blocking operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, blocking, pcap4j

I'm working on a packet sniffer but I'm getting trouble about the way to stop a thread (without deprecated methods) containing a blocking method.

The concerned method is the `loop()` one from pcap4j library. As it is a blocking method, I put it into a thread to keep the main one working. However, in order to apply a filter to the pcap interface, I have to break the loop and restart it as the `breakloop()` function of the library returns an `InterruptedException`. So my idea was to kill the thread containing the method. But as I can't get into the library's loop causing the method to block, I'm unable to do it by checking whether the thread is interrupted or not.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loop(args);
    }
});
t.start();
```

How can I stop it ?

**EDIT** : What I did was to recompile the library from its source, removing the InterruptedException from the PcapHandle class.

Comment: The code, do you have the full part of it? The whole encompassing class or link to source?

Comment: Not now sorry but the only interesting part is there I guess (I really tried everything).

Comment: Can you show some code how you would have done it if the `Thread#stop` was not deprecated? Also, what's wrong with using `breakLoop`?

Comment: If ```stop``` was not deprecated, I would have called it from the main thread, then applied the filter to my ```pcaphandle``` and started a new thread. Concerning ```breakloop``` method, it returns an ```InterruptedException```.

Comment: I found some library that I think you are using which has API by the way and source available. We cannot help you if we cannot see the library or use case specifics? Anytime a thread can be interrupted that is the except that gets thrown.

Comment: The library is ```pcap4j``` and the class used to perform pcap actions is called ```PcapHandle```. Here is the documentation : https://kaitoy.github.io/pcap4j/javadoc/latest/en/org/pcap4j/core/PcapHandle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Thread#getAllStackTraces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--) you can obtain all the threads. [SO Has a few other answers to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java) as well for getting a hold of the threads. After finding the thread you can interrupt it. The `Thread.class` also has some other identifiers that may help find the thread too.

Edit: Are you using kaitoy/pcap4j ? if so [breakLoop()](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j/blob/f040e2f520ae4c560e82a6d64b464c36bd8af673/pcap4j-core/src/main/java/org/pcap4j/core/PcapHandle.java#L1049) Nothing can be done about the `InterruptedException`, thats how the library intended for it to be broken. I would look at putting an issue in with their github if they need to implement a feature.

```
import java.util.Set;

class TestStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
            if(thread.getName().equals("some-name")){
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that the interrupt method as no other effect than changing the boolean Thread.isInterrupted() which is useless in my case.

Comment: Why not? That exception that thrown is for that? Have you tried?

Comment: Now I wonder if I tried to call ```interrupt``` and then ```breakloop``` (which would be ridiculous I admit) I will try that tomorrow (1h34 in France) but thank you for all.

Comment: I saw your edit and I'm going to post this on their github thanks a lot for your work.